# Store copy of CakePHP SMTP Email on cPanel Webmail sent folder

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cpanel

I am using CakeEmail to send emails to users via CakePHP application. I user following code to send emails:

```
                    $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
                      'port'=>'465',
                      'timeout'=>'30',
                      'host' => 'ssl://*************',
                      'username'=>'***************',
                      'password'=>'***********'
                    );

                    $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
                    $this->Email->from = '***********';
                    $this->Email->attachments =array(getcwd().$filename);
                    $this->Email->to = '*************';
                    $this->Email->subject = 'Purchase Order (M/s.'.$party_name.') PO No. '.date('Y/m/').($last_id['Po']['id']+1);
                    $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';
                    try {
                        if ($this->Email->send('Respected Sir,<br><br>Please find P.O. in the attachment and also note please attach P.O. with your bill.<br><br>Thanking You<br><b>')) {
                            // Success
                            $this->Flash->success(__('The po has been saved and email sent successfully.'));
                        } else {
                            // Failure, without any exceptions
                            $this->Flash->error(__('The po has been saved and email not sent.'));
                        }
                    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                        // Failure, with exception
                        $this->Flash->error(__('The po has been saved and email not sent.'));
                    }
```

It works fine but doesn't store copy of email in cPanel Sent folder.

After researching

Comment: I don't believe it saves emails that are sent programmatically, try connecting to the server, and save it to sent folder.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix any idea how to save on server.

Comment: since you have cpanel there might an configuration option to save the email sent, otherwise look into IMAP and `APPEND`